# Open .hdr files with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, hdr

I try to read `.hdr` files like this:

```
img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
```

This gives me a 3-channel 8-bit `Mat` which is either (nearly) completely white or a very dark picture. So I suppose it only gives me one image of the exposure sequence? How do I get a proper `Mat` with all the information?

- OpenCV version is 3.1.0.
- HDR files used: http://people.csail.mit.edu/sparis/publi/2011/siggraph/ ("Input images")

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/db7/tutorial_hdr_imaging.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: This is an article about loading a list of image files, not a .hdr file.

Answer (score 1):

The data you have is the merged stack not individual exposures. To display it correctly, you need to tone-map the data. This is the correct procedure, for example:

```
Mat hdr = imread("xxx.hdr",-1); // correct element size should be CV_32FC3
Mat ldr;
Ptr<TonemapReinhard> tonemap = createTonemapReinhard(2.2f);
tonemap->process(hdr, ldr);
ldr.convertTo(ldr, CV_8UC3, 255);
```

Then display your ldr with highgui.

Comment: That's C++ for a python question, but it actually does answer it.  Good stuff.

Comment: HA HA! Too concentrated. Oh well.

Comment: Yes, tone mapping is what I am trying to open the files for. The point is, .hdr files have a bit depth larger than 8 bits per color and I want to avoid information loss for decent tone mapping results.

Comment: Yes, as you can see, I commented that the Mat type read should be CV_32FC3. Three channels of float. If you are able to check the source code, that's the format it should be decoded into. I'll take some time to check sources again.